# Grouping in pandas and assign repetition number (first, second, third)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
date    userid
2017-03    a
2017-04    b
2017-06    b
2017-08    b
2017-05    c
2017-08    c
```

I would like create a third column that indicates the number of times that the sample was repeated at that date, so the frame looks like this:

```
date    userid    repetition
2017-03    a    1
2017-04    b    1
2017-06    b    2
2017-08    b    3
2017-05    c    1  
2017-08    c    2
```

So far, I grouped it by userid and date, but I only found the way to get the total counts

```
data['newcol'] = data.groupby(['sampleid'])['date'].transform('count')
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cumcount`

```
In [282]: df.groupby('userid').cumcount().add(1)
Out[282]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
dtype: int64

In [283]: df.assign(repetition=df.groupby('userid').cumcount().add(1))
Out[283]:
      date userid  repetition
0  2017-03      a           1
1  2017-04      b           1
2  2017-06      b           2
3  2017-08      b           3
4  2017-05      c           1
5  2017-08      c           2
```

Or, assign

```
In [285]: df['repetition'] = df.groupby('userid').cumcount().add(1)

In [286]: df
Out[286]:
      date userid  repetition
0  2017-03      a           1
1  2017-04      b           1
2  2017-06      b           2
3  2017-08      b           3
4  2017-05      c           1
5  2017-08      c           2
```

Comment: you were quicker than me writing the problem!! Thank you so much!